# Do I need the .Net framework installed to run a vc++ 2008 exe?

Tags: .net, visual-c++

Does a vc++ exe require the .Net framework to run, or will it run without the framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless it is compiled with the [`/clr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s(VS.80).aspx) flag you do not need the .NET framework. Of course if your c++ exe uses any .net components via COM interop you're back to needing the framework installed.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Managed C++, then yes, you will. However, if you're making a pure C++ application, you should just need the [Visual C++ 2008 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en), which is a whole lot smaller.

Comment: Wait, vc++ has it's own runtime? yuck!

Comment: You don't need the runtime, if you link statically.

Comment: @ajl - is that comment serious?

Answer (score 3):

Certainly you will need the .Net Framework installed for running the application,
(If you want to see the target Framework version then go to Project tab and select *name of project* Properties in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 2):

Pure C++: no.
Check your compile and link options to see if it includes .Net options (/clr) or libraries.

If not sure, use DependencyWalker to see which DLL's are actually required by your application.